# Does Oracle 'NOT LIKE' expression do not return NULL?

Tags: oracle, null

I try to query a table with the following query:

```
select * from name where firstname NOT LIKE 'PETER%'
```

It is not returning any records where firstname is null. Is this some error or that is how it is? I come from a SQL Server background and getting confused with many things here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NULL is not matched with `LIKE`. You have to explicitly ask for it with `OR firstname IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Any comparison with `NULL` returns "unknown" - which in most cases is the same as "not true".

If SQL Server returns NULL values for `NOT LIKE 'PETER%'` than I'd consider that a bug in SQL Server.

Comment: MS SQL Server has a **deprecated** mode where null that can be compared just like normal values, using `=`, `<>` etc. I wouldn't call it a bug at this point, but an unfortunate feature.